# laravel ajax request error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**jQuery:**

```
$.get("{{URL::asset('index.php/items/sessionStore')}}" + '/' + itemIds,
    function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('items/sessionStore', 'ItemsController@sessionStore');
```

Controller

```
public function sessionStore($id)
{
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        echo $id;
        echo "ajax";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no ajax";
    }
}
```

My error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "message": "",
    "file": "D:\\wamp\\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your route to

```
Route::get('items/sessionStore/{$id}', 'ItemsController@sessionStore');
```